# how to set contents of setSingleChoiceItems in onPrepareDialog?

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity, android-alertdialog

Guys, in onCreateDialog i have this:

```
case DIALOG_REVIEW: {
    if (bundle.containsKey("POSITION")) {
    final int position = bundle.getInt("POSITION");
    ArrayList<String> alterNumbers = numbers.get(position);
    final String[] phoneNums = new String[alterNumbers.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < alterNumbers.size(); i++) {
        phoneNums[i] = alterNumbers.get(i);
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle(names.get(position) + "'s number(s)");
    dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(phoneNums, 0,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                int which) {
            // get selected item and close the dialog
            String selectedNumber = phoneNums[which];
            updateUserSelectedNumber(position , selectedNumber);
            }
        });
    return dialog.create();
    }
```

which is working and great.

BUT pay attention to line

```
dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(phoneNums, 0,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
```

phoneNums are suppose to be changing each time the dialog pops up.
I've overriden onPrepareDialog method but I don't know how to assign new values to it.
and also there is no setSingleChoiceItems there.

here is my onPrepareDialog method

```
case DIALOG_REVIEW: {
    final int position = bundle.getInt("POSITION");
    ArrayList<String> alterNumbers = numbers.get(position);
    final String[] phoneNums = new String[alterNumbers.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < alterNumbers.size(); i++) {
    phoneNums[i] = alterNumbers.get(i);
    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
    alertDialog.setTitle(names.get(position) + "'s number(s)");
    ???
    break;
}
```

What is the solution?
thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use [getListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getListView()) method from AlertDialog class. Then use [setItemChecked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int,%20boolean)) method on returned object. Example:

`alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(1, true);`

Answer (score 7):

I just faced the same problem:

Two solutions:

1/ The fast and dirty

Delete the Dialog each time you have finished with it => onPrepareDialog will not be called so you wont have problems with data update:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    ...
    case DIALOG_REVIEW: {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle(names.get(position) + "'s number(s)");
        dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(phoneNums, 0,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            // get selected item and close the dialog
            String selectedNumber = phoneNums[which];
            updateUserSelectedNumber(position , selectedNumber);
            removeDialog(DIALOG_REVIEW);
        }
    });
    return dialog.create();
}
```

if you prefer, you can put a [onDismissListener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog) and do the removeDialog on the dialog dismiss.

---

2/ The quite pretty one

In the onPrepareDialog method just replace the old ArrayAdapter used by the dialog by a fresh new one:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_REVIEW:
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, android.R.id.text1, phoneNums);
            AlertDialog ad = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            ad.getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
        break;
        default:
            super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);
    }
}
```

I use the same method than the one used by android (the AlertController.java L. 854 of the froyo source code) to populate the dialog the first time.