# How actualize setMultiChoiceItems items values in onPrepareDialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I show dialog of checkboxes (list retrieved from DB) to allow user select, which rows remove. Because android dialog caching, I need to refresh count and names of checkboxes.
In my onCreateDialog:

```
dialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
       .setTitle( "Remove Items" )
       .setMultiChoiceItems( items, _selections, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked){}} )
       .setPositiveButton("Smazat", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
            dialog.dismiss(); 
            deleteRow(_selections);
            } })
        .setNegativeButton("Storno", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
            dialog.dismiss(); 
            } })
       .create();
```

How refresh values (items,_selections) in onPrepareDialog?
I tried invalidate views, hoping that force android to load items againg(dont work neither), but I think its bad choice as well as removing dialog and recreating.

```
protected void onPrepareDialog(final int id, final Dialog dialog) {
          switch (id) {
          case REMOVE_DIALOG_ID:

              ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                lv.invalidateViews();

          break;
          }
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a list of items using `AlertDialog.Builder`, it internally takes that and creates a `ListAdapater` that is dependent on the type of data you passed.  Since "items" in your example doesn't look like a resource ID, I'm assuming it's either a CharSequence[] or a Cursor.  If you provide more information about what "items" is, I can provide a more concrete example.

- For `CharSequence[]` (like String[]) data, `Builder` creates an ArrayAdapter instance.
- For `Cursor` data, `Builder` creates a CursorAdapter

You will need to obtain a reference to this ListAdapter using `getListView().getAdapter()` on the AlertDialog instance.

For a Cursor, you can get away with calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you have called `requery()` to update the data set.

Since you can't "update" an array with new data (changing the pointer to a new instance is not the same thing...the instance that the adapter is pointing to stays unchanged), this case is a little more work.  You will need to call the `add()`, `clear()`, etc. methods of the adapter to remove invalid items and add the updates ones.  With the adapters data set fully updated, you may now call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 2):

I spent  lot of time  to search for same solution  and eventually  fixed my problem with simple stuff after trying to use  onPrepareDialog too

I use the removeDialog(int) function of the Activity. When a dialog is dismissed, the Activity basically stores the state of the dialog (for performance reasons I would imagine). Calling removeDialog(int) on the dialog forces the activity to unload all references for the dialog and dismisses it from the screen if it's being shown.

did this when my activity lost focus simply add:

```
 public void onStop() {
            removeDialog(Id_Dial);
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

My technique is to create an adapter with empty data in `onCreateDialog` and completely replace the adapter during `onPreparDialog`.

Example:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {

        case DialogMergeRegion:

            title = ...

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseDataTabView.this)
                       .setTitle(title)
                       .setMultiChoiceItems(new CharSequence[0], null,
                                            new OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                                                    manageSelectionList(which, isChecked);
                                                }
                                            })
                      //...
                      .create();
        }
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

    switch (id) {


        case DialogMergeRegion: {

            List<String> regionNames = ...// get the data
            ListAdapter mergeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, regionNames);

            AlertDialog ad = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            ad.getListView().setAdapter(mergeAdapter);

            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onPrepareDialog method, instead of using invalidateViews(), you should try getting the adapter of the ListView and try calling either notifyDataSetChanged() or  notifyDataSetInvalidated(). Does that help?

Comment: `ListView diaglist= ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
ListAdapter diaglistAdapter= diaglist.getAdapter();` Do you mean something like that?

Comment: yes something like that, although I would cast that to a BaseAdater like so: BaseAdapter diaglistAdapter = (BaseAdapter) diaglist.getAdapter(); and then use diaglist.notifyDataSetChange(). if that does not work, try diaglist.notifyDataSetInvalidated()

Comment: nothing change in both cases, dialog still show cached content. I found some similar problems, but unanswered:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811688/how-to-set-contents-of-setsinglechoiceitems-in-onpreparedialog)

Comment: I would then suggest that you move your .setMultiChoiceItems() into the onPrepareDialog method, as this is always called before displaying any dialog, so this would force a refresh of your list items.

Comment: I tried, but cannot solve, how access dialog again, only ((AlertDialog) dialog) doesnt have .setMultiChoiceItems

Comment: It seems suitable choise is ((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(id) but how get id of list items